# What does [] (empty brackets) mean as a struct initializer argument?

Tags: swift

Below is some code from Apple's Foundation that I'm trying to port to JavaScript.

```
    struct UnarchiverFlags : OptionSet {
        let rawValue : UInt
        
        init(rawValue : UInt) {
            self.rawValue = rawValue
        }
        
        static let none = UnarchiverFlags([])
        static let finishedDecoding = UnarchiverFlags(rawValue : 1 << 0)
        static let requiresSecureCoding = UnarchiverFlags(rawValue: 1 << 1)
        static let startedDecoding = UnarchiverFlags(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    }
```

[(Source)](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/8f08574618e2654ccda730301e31aa73ecc4c5dc/Sources/Foundation/NSKeyedUnarchiver.swift#L25-L36)

I can't seem to figure out what the first static property is doing. It appears to be passing an empty array `[]` to the initializer, which expects a `UInt`. When I try to run some similar sample code, it fails:

```
func printNum(_ num: UInt) {
    print(num)
}

printNum(1)
printNum([])
```

```
$ swiftc -o main main.swift
main.swift:6:10: error: cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type 'UInt'
printNum([])
         ^~
compiler exit status 1
```

So what's really going on here, and how can I convert this to proper JS?

Comment: Where does JavaScript factor in here? Isn't `[]` just an empty array in this context?

Comment: Because that's how you can add multiple values with OptionSets (since it's bit flag), you pass it with an array. You could use `UnarchiveFlags([.finishedDecoding, startedDecoding ]` for instance. See the doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the superclass

Comment: `OptionSet` is not a superclass; it's a protocol.